# Delete an element from array within array of object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

My collection structure

```
{
        "companyName": "iAssure",
        "companyDepartment": [
           {
              "Department": "IT",
              "companysubDepartment": [
                  "HR",
                  "Finance",
                  "Account"
              ]
           },
           {
              "Department": "Production",
              "companysubDepartment": [
                  "Raw Material",
                  "Quality"
              ]
           }
        ]
    }
```

I want to delete `HR` from `companysubDepartment` where Department is `IT`

Comment: Is any thing you tried ?

Comment: yes. I tried this query 
db.companySettings.update({'_id':"9uvjCujcjSbbLYi86"},{'companyDepartment':{$elemMatch:{'Department':"IT"}}},{$pull:{'companysubDepartment':"HR"}); but it return only Matched:1 not delete element

Answer (score 0):

You missed [$ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/) in update.

Check following query :

```
db.companySettings.update({'_id':"9uvjCujcjSbbLYi86","companyDepartment":
                          {"$elemMatch":{"Department":"IT"}}},
                          {"$pull":{"companyDepartment.$.companysubDepartment":"HR"}})
```

Comment: **[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**

Comment: Its compulsory that we have 15 reputations for voting. I don't have 15 reputations